# Bash script concat strings command not found

Tags: bash

I am trying to run this simple bash script:

```
file_name=deploy
 echo "Init File NAme $file_name"
current_time=$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S")
echo "Current Time : $current_time"

new_fileName="${file_name}${current_time}.zip"
echo "New FileName: $new_fileName"
#echo $new_fileName ./app/code/community ./app/code/local ./app/design/frontend/indigo ./app/design/frontend/default 
#zip $new_fileName ./app/code/community ./app/code/local ./app/design/frontend/indigo ./app/design/frontend/default
```

But for some reason I receive:

```
Init File NAme deploy
Current Time : 2015.10.01-16.04.02
./ManualPack.sh: line 5: $'\r': command not found
.zip5.10.01-16.04.02
```

I know its very very simple to any beginner in bash, but I tried for a decent amount of time, with many Stack Overflow threads to make it work, but the output remains the same.

Comment: It is working fine on my linux server. Did you copy/pasted? Maybe there are some invisible characters messing with you (like `\r`). Try to write it all again by hand, no copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have Windows styled line terminators in your file (`\r\n`). Converting the file with [dos2unix](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) should help.